# Scraping Stack Overflow with BeautifulSoup returns nothing

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio

I have the following code here:

```py
url = f"https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22python+help%22"
async def scrape():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as r:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(await r.read(), features="lxml")

    questions = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "flush-left js-search-results"})[0]

asyncio.run(scrape())
```

But it returns an `IndexError` for questions. Even though when I inspect the page, it clearly has a `div` with class `flush-left js-search-results`.
[image]

Comment: That's likely because the page is dynamic, the content is generated on the fly or loaded from several sources. You'd be better off accessing its API directly. See [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/does-stack-overflow-provide-a-public-api-for-querying).

Comment: too often and you will also incur a ban.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the entire stackoverflow database, [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/)

Or use the APi as mentioned in the comments.